# Don't show gwibber messages in indicator applet

Tags: indicator, gwibber, messaging-menu

Gwibber turns the indicator-applet-icon blue, each time a new tweet appears in my timeline, which is always.

It is therefore no longer usefull as a "there is a new message for you" resulting in many missed jabber/gtalk chats, finding emails half an hour late and so on.

How can I mute Gwibber in there? Preferably so it only turns the new-message-icon blue on new replies and private messages in Gwibber. But certainly not on any update.